# Unable to test unreachable return statement after try catch block

Tags: java, spring-boot

I wrote a boolean function.

```
    public boolean func(String someString) {
    try {
        if (someCondition) {
            return true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The last return is unreachable however. But i wrote it to satisfy the function.
When i was writing test cases for this function, there is no way to cover that last return in the above code. So is there any way to modify the function to remove the unreachable code.
Thanking you in advance.

Comment: It can be reached if ```someCondition``` evaluates as ```false```

Comment: You can write `return` statement either in `try-catch` block or out of it i.e. `last return`. No need to write at both the places.

Comment: @AbhiN The return in the catch block only returns when an Exception is caught. But the return at the end is still necessary if there was no exception, and the condition of the `if` was not true.

Comment: If it's supposedly unreachable why are you executing the test?

Comment: Having a blank catch statement isn't good. I would suggest, at least, do "e.printStackTrace();"

Comment: @NomadMaker It's not blank. If there was a problem, it returns false. In real production code, you'd probably want to differentiate between `false` as a result of error or `false` as a result of the condition not being met, but it's not always necessary, and even if it is, a stack trace may not be the correct solution. A stack trace is the recommendation for beginners who leave the catch blank.

Comment: The problem is that this program is catching Exception. If it was meant for a useful purpose, then it would be catching specific exceptions rather than all of them.

Comment: @NomadMaker The problem stated in the question is imaginary.

Answer (score 2):

> The last return is unreachable

This is incorrect.

Think carefully about *when* the last return will be reached. It will only be reached when:

- `try` does not throw an exception (otherwise it will return in `catch`), and;
- it does not return in `try`. (or in more technical terms, "the `try` block completes normally")

When will it return in `try`? Because there is an `if` statement and no `else`, it will only return in `try` if `someCondition` is true. If `someCondition` is false, the `try` block completes normally, and the last return will be reached.

You just need to think of a test case where `someCondition` is false!

Answer (score -1):

Do it like this:

```
public boolean func(String someString) {
boolean bool=false;
    try {
        if (someCondition) {
            bool=true
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return bool;
}
```

Comment: Why? It's written fine as it is, and the OP seems to want to return false when there is an Exception, without stack tracing it. The OP just needs a test case that covers the case when `someCondition` is not true, but there is no exception.

Comment: whenever you put return between any code then rest of the block becomes unreachable always!! so it shoulnt be an issue.

Comment: That is incorrect. Only when you put a return in *all paths that lead to that code*. In the OP's code, the final return was reachable. try going line by line, consider `someCondition` to be `false`. So it will not perform the `return` in the `if`. And there is also no exception, so it does not perform whatever is in the `catch` block. So... it continues to the last line.

Answer (score -2):

Move the return up in the try block like so:

```
public boolean func(String someString) {
    try {
        if (someCondition) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```